# Grepping last 5 minutes log

Tags: command-line, text-processing, log

I need to grep last 5 minutes log.
log file:

```
18-06-17 06:00:09 ID-5
18-06-17 06:00:11 ID-78
20-06-17 09:34:51 ID-Hello
21-06-17 09:20:49 link is down
22-06-17 06:00:11 ID-674
22-06-17 06:40:51 ID-2
22-06-17 06:40:55 ID-7
22-06-17 06:40:16 ID-3
22-06-17 06:42:20 ID-2

date +"%d-%m-%y %k:%M:%S"
22-06-17 06:43:40
```

I tried:

```
awk -v date=$(date -d "30 minutes ago" +"%d-%m-%y %k:%M:%S") '$1" "$2 >= date { print $0 }' log
```

but have the error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: 06:43:40
awk: cmd. line-1-   ^ syntax error
```

Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: How is this using `grep`?

Comment: You can't do direct datetime comparisons with operators `=`,`>`, `<`etc. in `awk` - you'll either need to use a language that provides a "datediff" type module, or convert the datetime strings to epoch seconds (in GNU awk, you can do that with some basic string manipulation followed by the `mktime` function - see [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) for example)

Answer (score 0):

If your date/time was structured yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss instead of day first, then you could perform string comparisons to filter on lines after a given date.  To reformat the data use

```
sed 's/\(..\)-\(..\)-\(..\)\(.*\)/\3-\2-\1\4/' log > log.reformatted
```

You can then use awk to print lines after a given date and time by concatenating them together, e.g.

```
awk '$1 " " $2 >= "17-06-22 06:40:00"' log.reformatted
```

Your use of date to obtain the time 30 minutes ago is good - just change it to  be in year-month-day format.  You don't need the print $0 action since that is implied if no action is specified.

Note that I assume that "grepping" is intended to mean using Unix tools to filter for a desired subset of the available data.

The original error is likely due to a space between the date and time so that the `-v` argument only receives the date, while the time appears as a separate argument, confusing awk.  To resolve this use the `%H` format rather than `%k` (since your log format is two digit hour anyway), and remove the space between day and hour (as a simplistic solution to the problem).  Then the whole solution becomes:

```
sed 's/\(..\)-\(..\)-\(..\)\(.*\)/\3-\2-\1\4/' log |
awk -v date=$(date -d "30 minutes ago" +"%y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S") '$1$2 >= date'
```

Comment: I use now:
sed -n "/$(date "+%d-%m-%y")/,\$p" log
but in result I have all data for current day.
Added %H:%M:%S, but not working
sed -n "/$(date "+%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")/,\$p" log

Comment: `sed` will only work on an exact match - it won't provide you with the "greater than" feature that you want.  `awk` can do that.  In your `sed` examples you will get every line for a particular date, or for a particular second.  Another problem with this approach is if your starting time is 31-05-17 23:59:59 it will not match on lines for 01-06-17 00:00:00, etc.

Answer (score 0):

All in one `awk` command, compatible with `gawk`, `mawk`, and the [POSIX awk spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

```bsh
$ awk -F '[- ]' -v target="$(date -d '30 minutes ago' +'%y-%m-%d %T')" '
    { time = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%02d %s", $3, $2, $1, $4) }
    time >= target
  ' log
```

First, I'm invoking `awk` in a manner that accepts hyphen and space as delimiters, which makes for simpler parsing of the date. The `awk` command line also calls `date` to define a `time` variable in format yy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS (from most significant unit to least so that it can be sorted).

The first line within `awk` uses that same time format to set the `time` variable for each line of the log.  The second line then asciibetically compares the log line's time to the target time.  `awk`'s default action is to print, so it prints the line.

Using "30 minutes ago" relative to the question's "22-06-17 06:43:40":

```bsh
$ awk -F '[- ]' -v target="$(date -d '2017-06-22 06:13:40' +'%y-%m-%d %T')" '
    { time = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%02d %s", $3, $2, $1, $4) }
    time >= target
  ' log

22-06-17 06:40:51 ID-2
22-06-17 06:40:55 ID-7
22-06-17 06:40:16 ID-3
22-06-17 06:42:20 ID-2
```